# Durandal get view data in header main container

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I want to pass data from view js to main js. Main js is for main container which contains views please let me know how it can be done I my using knockout and durandal.

Main container

```
<div>
    <div class="lb-main-content">
        <audio id="audioPlayer"></audio>
        <div class="content-wrapper student-shell" style="margin-left:0px">
            <div class="lberror" style="display: none" id="errorContainer">
                <i class="icon-close alert"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="container-fluid page-host"
                data-bind="router: { transition:'entrance' }"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-container"></div>
</div>
```

js file

```
define(function(require) {

    var router = require('plugins/router');
    var ko = require('knockout');
    var Datahandler = require('lbdatahandler');
    var datahandler = new Datahandler();
    var CookieHandler = require('lbcookiehandler');
    var cookiehandler = new CookieHandler();

    // var dialog = require('plugins/dialog');
    // dialog.MessageBox.setDefaults({ "class": "modal-window" });



    return {
        router : router,
        activate : function() {
            router
                    .map(
                            [
                                    {
                                        route : 'student/activity-sociolearner/:courseid/:lessonid/:activityid(/:submissionid)',
                                        title : 'Sociolearner Activity',
                                        moduleId : 'student/activity-sociolearner',
                                        cssClass : 'student-rec-page',
                                        nav : false,
                                    }, {
                                        route : '',
                                        title : 'My Courses',
                                        cssClass : 'my-coursesMenuItem',
                                        moduleId : 'student/my-courses',
                                        nav : this.isStudent(),
                                    }, ])
                    .buildNavigationModel()
                    //.mapUnknownRoutes('#', 'student/my-courses');
                    .mapUnknownRoutes('notfound/notfound', 'notfound');
                    //.mapUnknownRoutes('#');

            return router.activate();
        },
        attached : function(view) {

        },

    };
});
```

view js file

```
define(function(require) {
    var Backend = require('./backend');
    var ko = require('knockout');
    var router = require('plugins/router');
    var app = require('durandal/app');
    var StorageHandler = require('lbstoragehandler');
    var storageHandler = new StorageHandler();
    var Datahandler = require('lbdatahandler');

    var that = this;
    var service = new Backend();
    var datahandler = new Datahandler();

    that.helpCourse = false;

    // var HELP_COURSE = 'helpcourse';

    return {
        activate : function(courseid) {

        },

    };
});
```

Comment: Right now it's a lot of work to try to answer your question: we'll have  to read through all the code to find out what's relevant and how things fit together. It  would be nice if you could take the time to trim away some of the stuff that's not relevant to the specific problem. Try to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that makes it clear what the problem is.

Comment: please check now i want to pass array data from view js to main js file

Comment: Give us a specific example. What data do you want to pass? Have you tried using Durandal's built in pub/sub messaging feature?
 http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Leveraging-Publish-Subscribe.html